# ADF pipeline, web activity has dynamic content where double quote character is replaced

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm looking to run an web activity as part of an ADF pipeline.
When developing the parameters in Postman, the API call includes the 'cols' parameter e.g.

`baseurl/api/v2/object/?cols=["id","First_name","last_name"]`

however when the pipeline is run in debug mode ADF puts a \ character before each ". ie.

`baseurl/api/v2/object/?cols=[\"id\",\"First_name\",\"last_name\"]`

Is there something i'm doing wrong? and is there a simple way to prevent the \ character being inserted?

Thanks

--edit-- tried the following
replacing " with the following combinations

`'"`  (single quote, double quote)

`''`  (single quote, single quote)

`\"`  (backslash, double quote)

`""` (double quote, double quote) =  result `\"\"`

replace(variable, '££', '"')  create variable and wrap it with replace cannot remember exact replace format but still resulted in `\"`

`json('"field", "field2"')` = result `json('\"field\", \"field2\"')`

Comment: We cannot remove the backslash, because it is an escape character.

Comment: Hi @Bruce Davison, we've sent a issue to MS Q&A, please see my updated answer. If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Very thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**
We've sent a issue to MS Q&A [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/186685/keep-quotation-marks-in-request-body-when-copy-dat.html).  Hope this is helpful for you.

Wherever there are double quotes, there are backslashes.
If your string type is a json string type like ({"id": "id_no","First_name":"name_string"}), then we can remove the backslash via `@json(JSON_String)` function,because it will convert string type to json type and also remove escape characters. Otherwise, we cannot remove the backslash if it is a string type.